# Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean but when I run the query in SQL, it works fine

Tags: php, mysql

I know most of the time this error means that you made a typo in your query but I cant seem to find anything wrong. When I run this query in phpmyadmin(with the variable of course replace by input), the results will show up.

So this is the code:

```
<?php
$mysqli= new mysqli('localhost','root','','something');
$query= $mysqli->prepare("select name,number,email,token from personen where token=?");
$query->bind_param("s",$token);
$query->execute();
?>
```

This error means my `$query` returns false right? I've checked everything myself on typos and I cant find a typo 100% sure. Is there anyway to find my mistake in this error?

Comment: `$token` which is unknownst to us could be the culprit. Compare it with what `var_dump($token);` produces against its value in the database. The link with which the question was closed with contains everything you need to use to debug.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah okay so I found out that I couldn't run 2 queries at the same time without store_result() or something. Anyway it's fixed now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you resolved it, but what you posted didn't support the question. Had you done that, then the outcome would have been different and the question wouldn't have been closed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah sorry I just had no clue what was wrong at the moment I made the question.

Comment: No problemo, *cheers*